# Using variable worksheet as formula destination in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing a fairly complicated macro, but the problem I am having is creating a formula on one sheet, in the code "Input_Sheet", to equate itself to a cell in a newly created worksheet, variably set as "ws". Each iteration of ws is named, so that's not an issue. I figured the correct way to do it was:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = " & ws.name & !R[" & totalRowCounter & "]C[" & totalColumnCounter & "]"
```

(Don't worry about the totalRowCounter & totalColumnCounter variables, they are defined appropriately). I just don't know why the formula isn't appropriately referencing the new ws sheet. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

You just need to take your `ws.name` out of the quotes, also adding an apostrophe before and after the sheet name will help with any sheets that may have a space in the name:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='" & ws.name & "'!R[" & totalRowCounter & "]C[" & totalColumnCounter & "]"
```

Comment: Thanks @ScottCraner, I was updating that and adding the apostrophe info

Comment: Thank you very much Wyatt. Can you explain, briefly, what exactly the & do? I recognize that I have had to use them when passing a variable as an argument... but I don't really get why.

Comment: They are used to concatenate various strings together, so you are concatenating =' with the sheet name and so on. In an excel formula, it would be equivalent to `=CONCATENATE(string1,string2)` or `=string1&string2`

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be the below:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=" & ws.name & "!R[" & totalRowCounter & "]C[" & totalColumnCounter & "]"
```

Comment: I thinks it's worth quite a lot as the answer is wrong otherwise ;)